# Adding font awesome icon dynamically causes page to scroll to top

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I'm dynamically adding content to my view through AJAX and javascript ERBs.  If the ERB contains a FontAwesome icon (SVG+JS), it causes the page to scroll to the top.

I have determined that using FontAwesome with web fonts and no JS does not cause this to happen.

My Javascript AJAX is similar to:

```
$.ajax({
   url:'\deliverable\addline',
   method:'get',
   dataType: 'script'
});
```

addline.js.erb ERB is similar to:

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render partial:'deliverables\new_line') %>").appendTo($('body'));
```

new_line.html.erb ERB Partial:

```html
<div>
<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
</div
```

Comment: Where are you doing that ajax request? that code shouldn't make it scroll, maybe there's something on the rest of the code.

Comment: Agreed.  I have determined that it is the introduction of the fontawesome javascript support.  If I only use the webfont and css version of fontawesome then the scrolling does not happen.